# Admob Mediation failure

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, admob

I am creating a game in Unity, in which i have added Google admob and Facebook Audience Network for ad's. When i am trying to run them individual ad network. They are running fine, but when i am trying to run them together as Mediation, i am getting following errors in my build.

```
Note: C:\Users\Chetan\Unity Projects\MinimumGame\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[:com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.5.1:] C:\Users\Chetan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0c207ca85139daebb053460673006b83\AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-51 Error:
Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [:com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.5.1:] AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-51
[:com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.5.1:] C:\Users\Chetan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0c207ca85139daebb053460673006b83\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ()


CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.28f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe 
-classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.28f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

 stderr[
 Note: C:\Users\Chetan\Unity Projects\MinimumGame\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 [:com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.5.1:] C:\Users\Chetan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0c207ca85139daebb053460673006b83\AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-51 Error:
 Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [:com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.5.1:] AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-51
[:com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.5.1:] C:\Users\Chetan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0c207ca85139daebb053460673006b83\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting
```

I am not able to understand why this happening, i had tried few solutions available online, but non of them had worked so far.
I am using software versions

- Unity 2019.4.28f1 (64-bit)
- GoogleMobileAds-v5.3.0 unity package
- facebook audience-network-unity-sdk-5.6.0

Kindly provide me some help to fix this issue, as it causing delay to make my game go live.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue while using Applovin mediation (it uses AdMob, Facebook Audience network and Unity Ads). in my case I ticked off "Custom Base Gradle Template" in player settings and removed Unity Ads package using the Package Manager and it worked.

Comment: I already tried that solution, but didn't worked for me.

Comment: @ChetanMehra The problem reoccurred for me as well (after changing nothing). I ticked off every box Publishing Settings > Build and ticked the one named Custom Launcher Gradle Template. After that the build was successful. Hope it will work for you.